# Как вернуться к нужной позиции на странице при нажатии кнопки Назад?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! Мучает вопрос, не смог найти на него ответ сам. У меня есть страница каталога с товарами, написал небольшой скриптик, чтобы отображались только первые 4 позиции, остальные открываются при нажатии на кнопку "показать все". При переходе на любую из видимых позиций и возврате из них обратно, возвращаешься к месту на странице откуда нажал на ссылку, но вот если отобразить все позиции и перейти по любой из них, то возвращает на страницу со скрытыми товарами. Может как то усложнить, чтобы при возврате все было как и в первом случае? А то не очень красиво получается.

Comment: Запоминаем ид позиции, переходим туда, возвращаемся, триггерим клик по "Показать все", список раскрылся, делаем скролл программно к айдишнику.

Comment: Я правда не особо пока дружу с JS, и многое не понятно пока, надо учиться писать код)) может есть хоть какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: это уже совершенно отдельная тема. Учите js и гуглите по каждому пункту вопросы. Например "js get element by id, js scroll to an element/id, js trigger click event"